# Param update also sending password nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, controller

I have update method where I have all user fields, I have also password input field, if use does not want to change password, I want to update withotu changing password, but if he chagnges password I want to update password too. But if I add params :password I get errror that password is required field. Following is my controller update method

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[edit update]

  def update
    @user.attributes = update_params
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = 'User has been successfully updated.'
      redirect_to admin_user_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Please fill all required fields'
      redirect_to new_admin_user_url(user: user_params)
    end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name,
                                 :last_name,
                                 :email,
                                 :division_id,
                                 :password,
                                 :employee_id)
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I am using same params for create method, this one is condensed code as actually code is very large. If I remove :password then it will update other fields, but I want if password is blank then it should not update neither validate, but if it is not empty than it should update password too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you submits your form with password field blank, params looks like this:

```json
{
  "user": {
    "first_name": "Jack",
    "last_name": "Sparrow",
    "email": "jack@sparrow.com",
    "division_id": 3,
    "password": "",
    "employee_id": 5
  }
}
```

So you are saying "update password to be blank" and your validations doesn't allow this. Just try removing param password when not needed:

```rb
def update
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
    end
    @user.attributes = update_params
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = 'User has been successfully updated.'
      redirect_to admin_user_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Please fill all required fields'
      redirect_to new_admin_user_url(user: user_params)
    end
end # Also, this end is missing in your code
```

Comment: Well I did using `@user.attributes = user_params.except(:password)` but is there not elegent way! delete/except seem strange.

Answer (score 0):

### Rails 6.1+

Few methods are added in Rails 6.1 in `ActionController::Parameters` to clean the params that you can use. The methods that are added are, `compact` and `compact!` in order to remove nil values from params hash and `compact_blank` and `compact_blank!` in order to remove blank values from params hash.